# Issue with urlencode

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with encoding ampersand in a filtering system.
If for example the first filter is for brands and the brand name is 'Head & Shoulders', the url should look like website/category/brand-head+%26+shoulders, but the filter works only if the url is website/category/brand-head-%252526+shoulders.
If there is another filter selected for example height the brand filter works if the url is website/category/brand-head-%25252526+shoulders and so on i have to add another 25 before percentage sign.

This is brand filter code

```
if($brand == false){
    $data['brands'] = array();
    $brands         = $attributes->getBrands($av_list, $_GET['c']);
    $brandTotalCnt  = 0;

    if(!empty($brands)){
        foreach ($brands as &$brand) {
            if($av_list){
                $cur_av_list  = $av_list  . $brand['brand'];
                $cur_av_uri   = $_GET['av'] . $brand['brand'];
            } else {
                $cur_av_list  = $brand['brand'];
                $cur_av_uri   = $brand['brand'];
            }
            $tmp_uri          = explode('/', $ln_uri);
            $tmp_uri_array    = $attributes->remove_items_by_value($tmp_uri, 'brand');
            $new_uri          = implode('/', $tmp_uri_array);   
            $brandTotalCnt   += $brand['num'];

            $data['brands'][] = array(
                    'brand'           => ucwords(strtolower($brand['brand'])),
                    'num'             => $brand['num'],
                    'href'            => $url->link('/c/'.$_GET['c'], '/brand-'. urlencode(strtolower($brand['brand'].'1')). $new_uri)
                );

        }
    }
    $data['brandTotalCnt'] = $brandTotalCnt;
}
```

Urldecode for every filter

```
if(isset($brand)){
    $sql .= " AND brand = '".urldecode($brand)."'";
}

if(isset($gramaj)){
    $height= $_GET['height'];
    $sql .= " AND height= '".urldecode($height)."'";
}
```

This is from my htaccess

```
# rewrite /category/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes
# to /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/([^-]+.+)/?$ /index.php/$2?c=$1 [L,QSA]

# rewrite /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
# converts any /name-val/ to query parameter name=val in every rewrite
# stopping when there is no part left after /index.php
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is the problem that more 25s are getting added or that you need to add these 25s in order to make your script work?

Comment: I need to add in order to make my script to work

Comment: Looks like every filter is doing a `urldecode`. Do you have `urldecode` in your script somewhere?

Comment: Yes for every filter i have urldecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP automatically parses the query string and URL-decodes the values during startup, when it populates `$_GET[]`.

It's correct to `urlencode()` the values when you generate an URL but you must not `urldecode()` the values you pick from `$_GET[]`.

**Update:**

As it is explained in the Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b):

> `mod_rewrite` has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences are unescaped at the time they are applied

If your rewrite rule takes a part of the path and puts it into the query string, the flag [`[B]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) (escape backreferences) instructs the engine to use the unescaped URL to match the rule.

You have two solutions for your problem:

1. (the simple solution): generate the URLs to **not** contain non-alphanumeric characters; use only letters, digits and dash (`-`) and you are safe;
2. (the advanced solution): add the `[B]` flag to the affected rewrite rules:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/([^-]+.+)/?$ /index.php/$2?c=$1 [L,QSA,B]
   ```

Comment: print_r($_GET) returns  Array ( [brand] => head [shoulders] => [c] => ingrijirea-parului )

Comment: Oops, this means the problem is somewhere else. Maybe on the rewrite rule? It sounds reasonable if Apache uses the URL-decoded path when it checks the rewrite rules. (The paths also needs to be URL encoded and you do that correctly. Apache needs to decode the path before looking for it into the file system). If this happens then the brand name lands in the query string unencoded and that leads to this output. Or maybe it encodes it?!

Comment: added my htaccess for the filter part

Comment: I found the problem and the solution in the Apache documentation and I updated the answer.

Comment: If i add the B flag, the filter works just for brand...for other 404

Comment: If one filter is active the second one selected returns 404 error

Comment: Your answer is good, maybe i should rethink the htaccess part

Comment: Maybe it would be better to replace the ampersand before you create the uri (eg: `str_replace('&', '-and-', $uri);`) and to reverse it right before you query the database. I recently had the same issue and that was the solution i settled with. :)

Comment: Maybe it clashes with the other rewrite rule. I would go for the simple solution: use only letters, digits and dashes in the friendly URLs.